# Android Bundles, using asset-packs to deliver app resources. Possible ? What is best Practice?

Tags: android

Trying to use Android bundles (.aab) as a way to get around 150MB upload limit on Play Store.
70% of my app is taken up by resources / media.
I am exploring the use of asset-packs and Dynamic Delivery to split off all resources into asset-packs and have them delivered at 'install-time'.

Has anyone done successful implementation of bundles by splitting-off resources and having them loaded at install time?

Comment: perhaps I should add a bit more context here. The 'app' is not a native Android app, actually it is a Cordova app that I want to publish in the play store..